# I need help for statistics homework

Tags: statistics

I have this problem:

There is a salesman that makes sales via WhatsApp. If someone says they wanna buy something, they send a delivery to their house. 20% of the people saying the wanted to buy didn't buy after all.

One day, the stock is low. The delivery has to go to 20 houses, but only has 17 products. What is the probability of leaving someone without their product?

I need to calculate this for 17 products (as in the statement) and for 19.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is also an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: There's no context, it's an isolated problem, I have no idea on how to start solving it, I just need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the sequence of deliveries as a set of Bernoulli trials. If we are 3 products short, then the event of not delivering on one of these products is the probability that 18 or more deliveries request their product (17 would be just enough). Conversely, this is the event that 2 or fewer customers decline the product. The probability that a customer declines is given to be $p=0.8$. So, using a sum of the PDF of the binomial distribution, the probability that $X<=2$ is given by
$$
P(X<=2) = P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)
$$
$$
P(X<=2) = (0.8^{20}) + (20\cdot0.2\cdot(0.8)^{19}) + (190\cdot(0.2)^{2}\cdot(0.8)^{18})
$$
$$
P(X<=2) \approx 0.2061
$$
For the case wherein we have 19 products, we are only potentially short in one case (the case where 0 customers decline the product), giving
$$
P(X=0) = 0.8^{20}\approx 0.01153
$$

Comment: Thanks, you're the only decent person, this actually really helped me, you're blessed man!